# 名前空間が設定されているライブラリを、複数クラス(複数ファイル)から呼び出す方法について

Tags: php, composer

**クラスを使用せず、1ファイルから呼び出す際は、下記で期待通り動作するのですが、**
index.php

```
require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
require_once('config.php');
new TwitterOAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
```

---

**複数クラス(複数ファイル)から呼び出す際、下記ではエラー発生します**

> Uncaught Error: Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found

config.php

```
 require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
 use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

HogeController.php

```
class HogeController extends Controller{
 new TwitterOAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
}
```

---

**複数クラス(複数ファイル)から呼び出す際は、どうやって記述すればよいですか？**

config.php

```
 require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
```

方法A.各クラス(各ファイル)毎に下記記述が必要ですか？
HogeController.php

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

class HogeController extends Controller{
 new TwitterOAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
}
```

方法B.そこからincludeする場合は、include先のファイルでも use が必要ですか？

HogeController.php

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

class HogeController extends Controller{
 include(dirname(__FILE__).'/twitter.php');
}
```

twitter.php

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

new TwitterOAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ちとご質問の意味を勘違いしているかもしれませんが、requireなどで読み込まれるファイルをうまく記述することで、`use`を各ファイルごとに記述しなくてもいいようにできないか?と言うことだと理解しました。

PHPの公式ドキュメントに以下のような記載があります。

[名前空間の使用法: エイリアス/インポート](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.namespaces.importing.php)

> **注意:**
>   インポート規則はファイル単位のものです。つまり、インクルードされたファイルは インクロード元の親ファイルのインポート規則を 引き継ぎません。

(公式サイトなのに単純な綴りミスがありますが、それは置いといて。)

### *複数クラス(複数ファイル)から呼び出す際は、どうやって記述すればよいですか？*

上記の記述から、

#### *方法A.各クラス(各ファイル)毎に下記記述が必要ですか？*

(「下記記述」がどこからどこまでを指すのかが不明ですが)
→`use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;`は各ファイルごとに必要

#### *方法B.そこからincludeする場合は、include先のファイルでも use が必要ですか？*

→Yes.

と言うことが導き出されます。あなたの経験された事象についても、きちんと公式サイトの記述通り動いているように思われます。

Comment: 「DRY」なコードとなるような方法があるかもと思い質問してみたのですが、各ファイル毎にuse記述が必要なのですね…